# Programatically send text using bluetooth socket to another bluetooth device in android

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-socket

> For sending data to another Bluetooth device programmatically, I am
>   using Bluetooth socket code.Whenever I called
>   bluetoothSocket.connect(); It gives connection refused or connection
>   to peer Exception.
>       I have one more confusion that which UUId I have to use in it or from where i can get it.Below is the snippet of code.

```
public void openBT() {
        UUID uuid = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"); // Standard
                                                                                // SerialPortService

        try {

            mmSocket = mmDevice.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid);
            Method m = mmDevice.getClass().getMethod("createInsecureRfcommSocket", new Class[] {int.class});
            mmSocket = (BluetoothSocket) m.invoke(mmDevice, 3);
            mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
            mmSocket.connect();
            /*mmSocket = mmDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid);

            mmSocket.connect();*/
            mmOutputStream = mmSocket.getOutputStream();
            mmInputStream = mmSocket.getInputStream();

            beginListenForData();

            myLabel.setText("Bluetooth Opened");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Help Appreciated..!!

Comment: can you share your exception logs here.

Comment: have a look on this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25577645/how-to-send-data-a-string-to-a-paired-device-in-android

Comment: By following above link now I am getting the exception "Connection refused" either I am paired with another device or not paired(In not paired case When I called bluetoothSocket.connect(); It's shows Pairing dialog to pair but when I clicked pair its gives  "Connection refused" Exception.So no luck till yet..!!